# Add field to collection with a condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, set, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

I want to add a new boolean field to a collection with other field's information.

My sample data is ;

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("50abae61edecb53c740022eb"), 
    "pull_request" : {
        "diff_url" : null, 
        "patch_url" : null, 
        "html_url" : null
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("50abae61edecb53c740022ec"), 
    "pull_request" : {
        "diff_url" : "https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/pull/106.diff", 
        "patch_url" : "https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/pull/106.patch", 
        "html_url" : "https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/pull/106"
    }, 
}
```

The new field is "hasPullRequest"; if pull_request field is null, hasPullRequest:false; otherwise hasPullRequest:true. I mean that below;

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("50abae61edecb53c740022eb"), 
    "pull_request" : {
        "diff_url" : null, 
        "patch_url" : null, 
        "html_url" : null
    },
    "hasPullRequest" : false
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("50abae61edecb53c740022ec"), 
    "pull_request" : {
        "diff_url" : "https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/pull/106.diff", 
        "patch_url" : "https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/pull/106.patch", 
        "html_url" : "https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/pull/106"
    }, 
    "hasPullRequest" : true
}
```

I tried this query but it didnt run;

```
db.getCollection('issues').aggregate([
   {
     $addFields: {
       hasPullRequest:  { 
            "$cond": {
            if: { { "$eq": {"$pull_request": null}} ,
            then: false,
            else: true
            } 
      }
   }
])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Condition `pull_request field is null` means you get `false` only for `pull_request: null` - however your first document is `pull_request: {diff_url:null, patch_url:null, html_url:null}` which is **not** "null"

Comment: `db.getCollection("Issues").find({"pull_request":null})`, It worked. If three of inner features are null, pull_request is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of some records has no pull_request field, I added a or condition;

```
    db.getCollection("test").aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          hasPullRequest: { 
             $cond: [ 
                 { 
                     $or:
                     [ 
                         { $and: [ 
                            { $eq: [ "$pull_request.diff_url", null ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$pull_request.patch_url", null ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$pull_request.html_url", null ] },
                                 ]
                         },
                         {  $eq:[{ $ifNull: [ "$pull_request", 0 ] },0]  }
                      ]
                  },
                 false, 
                 true 
             ] 
          } 
      } 
  },
  {
        $out: "Issues2"
  }
]
).pretty()
```

It perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your query condition - `{ "$eq": {"$pull_request": null}}`. It should be either of the following:

```
db.test.aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          hasPullRequest: { 
             $cond: [ 
                 { $eq: [ "$pull_request", { diff_url: null, patch_url: null, html_url: null } ] }, 
                 false, 
                 true 
             ] 
          } 
      } 
  }
] ).pretty()

db.test.aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          hasPullRequest: { 
             $cond: [ 
                 { $and: [ 
                        { $eq: [ "$pull_request.diff_url", null ] },
                        { $eq: [ "$pull_request.patch_url", null ] },
                        { $eq: [ "$pull_request.html_url", null ] }
                 ] },
                 false, 
                 true 
             ] 
          } 
      } 
  }
] ).pretty()
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

```
db.test.aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $facet: {
           pull_req_no: [
               { $match: { pull_request: { $exists: false } } },
               { $addFields: { hasPullRequest: false } }
           ],
           pull_req_yes: [
               { $match: { pull_request: { $exists: true } } },
               { $addFields: { 
                      hasPullRequest: {
                          $cond: [ 
                              { $and: [ 
                                  { $eq: [ "$pull_request.diff_url", null ] },
                                  { $eq: [ "$pull_request.patch_url", null ] },
                                  { $eq: [ "$pull_request.html_url", null ] }
                              ] },
                              false, 
                              true
                          ]
                      }  
               } }
           ]
      }
  },
  {
      $project: { result: { $concatArrays: [ "$pull_req_no", "$pull_req_yes" ] } }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$result" 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$result" } 
  }
] ).pretty()
```

Comment: I add `$out: "Issues"` end of the query, then It works, thanks a lot.

Comment: some items has no pull_request field, how can i add it to this query; 
`{ $or: [ 
                        
{ $eq: [ "$pull_request", { diff_url: null, patch_url: null, html_url: null } ] },

                        { $eq: [ "$pull_request", null ] }
                 ] },`
I used or condition but it didnt work.

Comment: If _has no pull_request field,_ what is the output? `hasPullRequest:` is `false`. Okay. I will update the query shortly.

Comment: I see that you have solved the _has no pull_request field_ issue. The query I just wrote is a little verbose - see the updated post.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) like this:

```
db.getCollection('nameColl').aggregate([
   {
    $addFields: 
        {
            newField: 
                {
                    $cond: {if:{$eq:[{ $ifNull: [ "$field", 0 ] },0] }   , 
                    then: false, 
                    else: true }
                }
        }       
}        
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
db.issues.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      hasPullRequest: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$pull_request",
                  null
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $objectToArray: "$pull_request"
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $objectToArray: "$pull_request"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $size: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: {
                          $objectToArray: "$pull_request"
                        },
                        cond: {
                          $ne: [
                            "$$this.v",
                            null
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          false,
          true
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LFor0SQ4bQR)